# Xmr-Stak miner constantly crashes

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, ubuntu, xmr-stak-amd

I am trying to use [XMR-Stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak) to mine a crypto-currency called electroneum(crypto-night) but it keeps crashing with the log:

```
GLib: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop 2
((src/devices/nm-device.c:1452)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: Invalid PCI ROM header signature: expecting 0xaa55, got 0xffff
```

I'm thinking it's a RAM issue, or maybe a new desktop will fix it. I also posted on Ubuntu.